# Unban is not defined

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'unban',
  aliases: ['uban', 'unban'],
  category: 'misc',
  permissions: ['BAN_MEMBERS'],
  description:
    'Use this command to permanately or temporary ban a server member from Sekai.',
  /**
   * @param {Discord.Message} message
   * @param {Array} args
   */
  async execute(message, args) {
    if (message.mentions.users.size === 0)
      return message.reply('Please mention a user to unban ❌');
    const targetid = message.mentions.users.first().id;
    if (targetid === message.client.user.id)
      return message.reply(
        "Me? Really? That's not very nice, I guess you failed "
      );
    const targed = await message.guild.members.cache.get(targetid);
    let reason = [];
    if (args.length >= 2) {
      args.shift();
      reason = args.join(' ');
    } else reason = 'No Reason provided';
    try {
      let extra = '';
      try {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Moderation message regarding on your **BAN**')
          .setAuthor("Joony's Den")
          .setDescription(
            `you have been banned from **${message.guild.name} ✅ **\nReason for ban: **${reason}\n${extra}**`
          )
          .addField('Contact','If you believe that your ban was unjustified, please feel free to contact any of these staff members. **JOONY#9513** or any of administrators online.')
          .setColor('#2243e6')
          .addField('Appeal Accepted?','if your appeal was accepted, please join using this link. your link will expire after 1 use. **https://discord.gg/4yuCzUC7aw**')
          .addField(
            'Appeal',
            'Because you have been banned from the server, you will have one chance to appeal . Your appeal will be processed to the administrators or appeal managers ✅ **[CLICK HERE TO APPEAL](https://forms.gle/atc75ZftpdfJhfH56)**'
          );
        targed.send(embed);
      } catch (error) {
        extra = 'Messaging the user has failed! ❌';
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        targed.unban(targed, [reason])
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('User unbanned')
          .setDescription(
            `${
              targed.tag || targed.user.username
            } has been sucessfully unbanned from **${
              message.guild.name
            } ✅ **\nReason for unban: **${reason}\n${extra}**`
          )
          .setColor('#FA2657');

        message.channel.send(embed);
      }, 2000);
    } catch (error) {
      message.channel.send(
        `I could not unban the given member, make sure that my role is above member! ❌`
      );
    }
  },
};
```

Hello! how do I unban the user using this format, it has an error saying "guild.unban is undefined"
it has an error saying

targed.unban([reason])
^

TypeError: targed.unban is not a function
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Joon\Documents\GitHub\Discord-Bot\commands\misc\unban.js:49:16)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

Comment: If the Member is banned, how are you going to get them from `GuildMemberManager`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unban a `GuildMember` (a banned *user* is not a *member* of a *Guild*). You should call unban on `GuildMemberManager`. See https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=unban